# aSmack XMPP lib not working

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I am trying to make aSmack work in my project.
Created a standard project in eclipse, added the jar to build path / libraries. Started using the XMPP classes, but I am not sure if there's something else I should do to properly set up the project (later on that), since it's not working.
In a `Service`, I start an `AsnycTask` to connect to google talk and send one chat message.

```
conn1 = new XMPPConnection(config);
// connecting to the server
try {
    conn1.connect();
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "XMPP connected");
} catch (XMPPException xe) {
    msg = "XMPPException during connect(): " + xe.getMessage();
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, msg);
}

// login
try {
    conn1.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD, RESOURCE);
    msg = "login ok";
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, msg);
} catch (XMPPException xe) {
    msg = "XMPPException login(): " + xe.getMessage();
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, msg);

    StackTraceElement[] st = xe.getStackTrace();
    for (int i = 0; i<st.length; i++) { 
        msg = xe.getStackTrace()[i].toString();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, msg);
    }
}

// creating a chat and sending messages
try {
     ChatManager chatmanager = conn1.getChatManager();
     msg = "creating chat";
     Log.v(LOG_TAG, msg);
     Chat chat = chatmanager.createChat(BUDDY_ADDRESS, new MessageListener() {

        @Override
        public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
            String msg = "incoming chat: " + message;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, msg);
        }
    });
    chat.sendMessage("ahoj");
} catch (XMPPException xe) {
    msg = "XMPPException during connect(): " + xe.getMessage();
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, msg);
}
```

(Please overlook my stupid exception handling, I'm still learning it :-)
The connect() method should work, since it doesn't throw an exception, in the Logcat howewer, before the "XMPP connected" message, there's an error, and then an exception thrown by the login() method:

```
03-01 15:13:19.970: WARN/System.err(4465): stream:error (text)
03-01 15:13:19.970: WARN/System.err(4465):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:261)
03-01 15:13:19.970: WARN/System.err(4465):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:44)
03-01 15:13:19.975: WARN/System.err(4465):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:71)
03-01 15:13:24.640: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3089): GC_EXPLICIT freed 610 objects / 39760 bytes in 216ms
03-01 15:13:26.370: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(2020): onDataConnectionStateChanged 3
03-01 15:13:26.380: DEBUG/MobileDataStateTracker(2020): replacing old mInterfaceName (pdp0) with pdp0 for hipri
03-01 15:13:26.395: DEBUG/MobileDataStateTracker(2020): replacing old mInterfaceName (pdp0) with pdp0 for supl
03-01 15:13:26.400: DEBUG/MobileDataStateTracker(2020): default Received state= CONNECTED, old= CONNECTED, reason= (unspecified), apnTypeList= default,supl
03-01 15:13:31.570: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2806): GC_EXPLICIT freed 173 objects / 10752 bytes in 207ms
03-01 15:13:34.550: VERBOSE/Smacktest_01(4465): XMPP connected
03-01 15:13:36.600: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2583): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1551 objects / 87688 bytes in 236ms
03-01 15:13:39.580: VERBOSE/Smacktest_01(4465): XMPPException login(): No response from the server.
03-01 15:13:39.585: VERBOSE/Smacktest_01(4465): org.jivesoftware.smack.NonSASLAuthentication.authenticate(NonSASLAuthentication.java:73)
03-01 15:13:39.605: VERBOSE/Smacktest_01(4465): org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:369)
03-01 15:13:39.605: VERBOSE/Smacktest_01(4465): org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:230)
03-01 15:13:39.620: VERBOSE/Smacktest_01(4465): com.biroalex.smacktest_01.SmackTest_01Service$AsyncXMPPConn.doInBackground(SmackTest_01Service.java:105)
03-01 15:13:39.620: VERBOSE/Smacktest_01(4465): com.biroalex.smacktest_01.SmackTest_01Service$AsyncXMPPConn.doInBackground(SmackTest_01Service.java:1)
03-01 15:13:39.635: VERBOSE/Smacktest_01(4465): android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
03-01 15:13:39.640: VERBOSE/Smacktest_01(4465): java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-01 15:13:39.655: VERBOSE/Smacktest_01(4465): java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-01 15:13:39.655: VERBOSE/Smacktest_01(4465): java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
03-01 15:13:39.660: VERBOSE/Smacktest_01(4465): java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
03-01 15:13:39.665: VERBOSE/Smacktest_01(4465): java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
03-01 15:13:39.705: VERBOSE/Smacktest_01(4465): creating chat
```

So the question is :) if I am doing something wrong, or the project is not prepared properly for the aSmack lib to be user on android?

There's the aSmack author's github https://github.com/rtreffer/asmack where he mentions that build environment, which is completely chinese for me. Shall I create a new build environment? How do I do that?

Thank you for your patience!

Comment: For others: you can also get a `stream:error (text)` if you join a room twice, see: http://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/35991

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my code works with an other open XMPP provider, so probably there's no serious error neither in my code, nor in my build environment or whatever, and most probably not in the aSmack lib :)
I'll play around to find out what happens when trying to connect to google, but the question is invalid for now.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC if you want to use gtalk with smack you have to supply the full JID as username: **user@gmail.com**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Google Talk is only working in polling mode: http://credentiality2.blogspot.com/2010/03/xmpp-asmack-android-google-talk.html

Comment: Now that I was able to check the link, it seems that that solution is only different in the way it receives the chat messages. Connecting and logging in is done the same way as I did, and my project fails already at the login - probably, maybe something is wrong during connecting too.

Comment: On the other hand, it is a good ide to try this whole XMPP thing on an other server, maybe google did some proprietrary modifications to gtalk.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this question and found the answer, or at least one that worked for me when I got this Exception. When you create your connection, do it like this:

```
    ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration(SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT);
    config.setTruststoreType("BKS");
```

Hope it helps :)